# Why only windowGainedFocus() does not work?

Tags: java, swing, focus, windowlistener

I have the following code, where I add a WindowListener to my JFrame, and I want to override the method `windowGainedFocus`:

```
    final JFrame jd = new JFrame();
    jd.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jd.setSize(300, 425);
    jd.setLayout(null);
    jd.setResizable(false);

    jd.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent windowEvent){
               System.out.println("TEST");
         }        
    });
```

But it is not working, when I focus this frame it doesn't print "TEST".
But when I override the method `windowClosing` it works:

```
    jd.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
               System.out.println("TEST");
         }        
    });
```

What's the problem with `windowGainedFocus()`?

Comment: Change `public void windowGainedFocus(..` to `@Override public void windowGainedFocus(..`

Comment: It still does not work :/ The method windowClosing worked without the `@Override`

Comment: Oh it worked now but I don't know why.... I simply changed `addWindowListener`  to `addWindowFocusListener`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jd.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
     public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent windowEvent){
           System.out.println("TEST");
     }        
});
```

Should be:

```
jd.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
     public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent windowEvent){
           System.out.println("TEST");
     }        
});
```

I *knew* there was a good reason I hated the adapter classes..  I would recommend using the listener rather than the adapter.